# Unable to connect with Azure SQL from Azure VM using Site-Site Connectivity

Tags: c#, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-vpn

We have created simple classic Azure VM and have Azure SQL.

We have an application running on VM and trying to do some operation on Azure SQL, however we are not able to access it and got generic exception

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections

We already did list of things:

1. Added VM's public IP in remote database server
2. Added Endpoints for 1433 TCP thru Azure Dashboard
3. Added Inbound rule for 1433 in VM' Firewall

**EDIT**

For site-to-site VPN,

1. we linked our database to cloud service of VM
2. traced IP of database, now we are able to telnet IP with 1433 within
   VM.

But still we are logging below error on logger when trying to interact with database.

> A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The target principal name is incorrect.

Are we missing something here

Comment: Did you try adding the ClientIP under SQL server firewall settings on azure portal as suggested in this post? https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/sql-database-configure-firewall-settings/

Comment: @AbhilashRVankayala as far as I am correct, we did it that on step 1.

Answer (score 1):

Generally connecting from Azure VM to Azure SQL is a bit different then connecting from outside of Azure.

assuming you are using the latest V12 Azure SQL and latest .Net framework or SSMS

you need to open on your VM outbound connection with TCP port range 11000-11999 and 14000-14999
make sure you do not have any blocker (firewall, 3rd party application that uses this port ranges)

from the Azure SQL end you can just click on "Allow Azure Services" on the Firewall configuration blade to allow connection from within Azure

you can read more about ports used when connecting to Azure SQL here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/sql-database-develop-direct-route-ports-adonet-v12/

and regards the Firewall configuration on Azure SQL you can read more here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/sql-database-firewall-configure/#connecting-from-azure

Comment: I have Allowed Azure Services on SQL, even tried 0.0.0.0 to 255.255.255.255 but its not working, test server on new VM is working fine though

Comment: did you check firewall on the VM that is not working? it might block the outbound connection? you can also ping from the VM to validate that Azure SQL name resolved correctly

Comment: yes it works fine on local though with same connection string, yes even tried with firewall off on VM

Comment: Sorry, but i might not understand the situation correctly, what is working local? and what is not?

Comment: connection string is ok, even works debugging on local, pings correctly

Comment: so, I understand that you are not able to use your application to connect to Azure SQL. can you share the connection string (remove user and passwords before sharing). and why debugging is relevant here?

Comment: we have site-to-site VPN running, I think that is problem

Comment: It might be, Please let me know if further assistance is required

Answer (score 0):

Facepalm moment for us.

Our internet wasn't working that is why we weren't able to connect to our database. As per web we did add MSFT's public DNS Servers i.e. 168.63.129.16 and 168.62.167.9. for classic VM's configure tab.

Comment: If you found the solution in the other answer, mark it as so for clarity?